# Computing limit with $e$

Tags: limits

I have got problem with computing limit below (showing that it is $0$).

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \cdot e -           \sqrt{n} \cdot (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = 0$

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansions?

Comment: Yes. I'm fimiliar with it.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}~n\bigg[e-\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)^n\bigg] ~=~ \frac e2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Taylor expansions:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}\left( e - \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) &= 
\sqrt{n}\left( e - e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)= 
\sqrt{n}\left( e - e^{n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)}\right) \\
&= \sqrt{n}\left( e - e^{1-\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)
= \sqrt{n}e\left( 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)\\
&= \sqrt{n}e\left( 1 - (1-\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right))\right) \\
&= \sqrt{n}e\left( \frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \\
&\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{e}{2\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: (why the downvotes, if I may?)

Comment: the downvotes are not for your answer I think

Comment: They seem to be (+2/-2), though. I'd be fine with it, if I understood why.

Comment: how can I see the (+2/-2)? I think I saw something about somebody saying  your answer was not rigorous, but that comment disappeared?

Comment: If you click on the $0$ between the two arrows, you'll see the breakdown of votes. As per the rigor of the answer, it seems quite rigorous to me (granted a familiarity with the $o(\cdot)$ and $\sim$ notations, that are [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations))

Comment: Agreed. In case of doubt, another possibility is to calculate the limit is to put $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$,  use the result mentioned by u55232 to obtain 0/0 and then l'hopital. But that seems to be more work though and then one needs to check if l'hopital is applicable to make it rigorous ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24276/discussion-between-wiskundeliefhebber-and-clement-c).